# Sitecore certificates validity expired

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, certificate

My Sitecore certificates are expired due to this all my instances content editor are down and showing below error

[image: Error]

As suggested in the [blog](https://blog.coates.dk/2018/11/08/sitecore-sif-newsignedcertificate-the-time-period-is-invalid/), I have created a new certificate for DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert but still, the issue is not resolved yet.
After the creation of sitecorerootcert do I need to create new certificates for xConnect and xConnect_client certificates or I'm missing something here. Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - Yes! If you've generated a new Root Certificate, you need to create a new certificate for xConnect_client in-order to maintain the Signer relationship with the Root Certificate.

PS: Also, Don't forget to add the App Pool user permission on certificate and update the latest Thumbprint of the new certificate under AppSettings.config (of xConnect instance) and ConnectionStrings.config (of Sitecore instance). Then recycle the app pool and it should fix the above mentioned error. Hope it helps!